# can't connect to web3 socket in mist console

Tags: web3js, mist

I want to connect to my local testnet with web3. The following code works when executed in Mist:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
console.log("Connected to Web3 Status: " + web3.isConnected());
```

The output of this code is:

> Connected to Web3 Status: true

However, when debugging in my Mist console with a break point after connecting to the Web3 socket, and when I input

```
web3.isConnected()
```

I am getting 'false', even though when continuing the code from Mist, it prints

> 'Connected to Web3 Status: true'

again.

How can I use the web3 socket from the mist browser console correctly?